# закрыть вкладку браузера C# по URL

Tags: c#, браузер

Здравствуйте, меня зовут Станислав и у меня есть вопрос для вас. Как можно допустим я запускаю Process.Start("https://www.yandex.ru"), как мне его закрыть исключительно только вкладку "https://www.yandex.ru"? 
P.S. Заранее спасибо за все ответы!

Comment: Здравствуйте, Станислав.

Comment: ставлю на то что это невозможно сделать в общем случае. Для каких-то браузеров может решения и есть.

Comment: Либо прямое управление браузером через движки вида Watin/Selenium где еще надо их будет пилить под себя. Либо непрямое через поиск контролов в окне браузера и эмуляцией нажатий мыши/посылкой клавиш окну.

Comment: Пример для FF http://csharphelper.com/blog/2011/09/close-mozilla-firefox-popups-in-c/